# Delete multiple rows mysql with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

please help in deleting multiple rows from a table.

**home.php**

```
 <form action="del.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="need_delete[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $row['listingtype'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['propertyname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['listdate'];?></td>


</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
<tr>
 <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr></form>
```

**del.php**

```
<?php
                 include "include/db.php";
                 $tbl_name='propertylistingbasicinfo';

                // Check if delete button active, start this
                if ( ! empty($_POST['delete'])) {
                    foreach ($_POST['need_delete'] as $id => $value) {
                        $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'.$tbl_name.'` WHERE `id`='.(int)$id;
                        mysql_query($sql);
                    }
                    header('Location: home.php');
                }

            ?>
```

Error : When i click on delete button, blank screen come. 
And url looks like this : http://localhost/realestate/del.php?need_delete%5B2%5D=2&delete=Delete

Comment: What's the reason to run a query for each record you want to delete?

Comment: He probably doesn't know about the `IN`. :-)

Comment: @ninetwozero: I'm afraid you're right. ;)

Answer (score 1):

your mixing up GET with POST, change form method to **post**

Answer (score 1):

You need something similar to this in your form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

then you can use implode() function to concatenate ids and remove them

```
$deleted = implode(',',$_POST['record']);
$query = mysql_query("delete from table where id in ('$deleted') ");
```

Not tested but this the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are submitting the form with method="get" and in del.php, you are accessing values from $_POST. Change method="get" to method="post" on home.php

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to the following...

`home.php`:

```
<form action="del.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="need_delete[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" />
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['listingtype'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['propertyname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['listdate'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`del.php:`

```
<?php
    //Get the db-file and set the table name
    include "include/db.php";
    $tbl_name='propertylistingbasicinfo';

    // Check if delete button active, start this
    if ( !empty($_POST['delete'])) {

        //Let's sanitize it
        $sanitized_post_ids = array();
        foreach($_POST['need_delete'] as $id ) $sanitized_post_ids[] = intval($id);

        //Get the ids and add a trailing ",", but remove the last one
        $in_str = substr(implode(',', $sanitized_post_ids), 0, -1);

        //Build the sql and execute it
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $tbl_name ' WHERE id IN (' . $in_str . ')'; 
        mysql_query($sql);

        //Redirect!
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
```

Hope this works out for you (and that I didn't manage to add a typo or similar misshaps)!